# Does this iff statement apply to totally ordered sets?

Tags: inequality, field-theory, relations

I was given that $(F,\leq)$ is an ordered field. I was able to prove the following statement:$$\forall a\in F:[\forall x \in F: x>0 \rightarrow x\geq a] \leftrightarrow a\leq 0$$

I was asked, whether this also applies to totally ordered sets or not, but I cannot really find, how to verify that. Isn't the only difference that if I use totally ordered sets, I can't just simply (for example) add a number to both sides of the inequality, which I however can do in an ordered field?

Comment: In an arbitrary ordered set, what is $0$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Exactly! But we can replace $0$ with $b$ in the original statement (and prepende $\forall b\in F$).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For a counterexample try the linear order $\Bbb Z$. If that’s not enough of a hint, I’ve left a bit more in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Try $a=1$.

Comment: Interesting... I think my proof from left to right might be flawed then. I came to the conclusion that the initial statement is correct, without actually using the fact that I am dealing with a field, so if my proof was correct I could just apply that to any set as well.

Comment: @M3xr: As you may be able to infer from this example, you really do need the fact that $0$ has no immediate successor in an ordered field.

Comment: I see. Thanks! So ordered fields will always be infinite as well... Things are starting to make sense now :)

Comment: @M3xr: You’re welcome! Yes, and in fact one can give a direct proof that ordered fields must be infinite, by noting that if a field $F$ is finite, there is some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\underbrace{1_F+\ldots+1_F}_n=-1_F$. If $F$ were ordered, this would mean that both $1_F$ and $-1_F$ were in the positive cone, and that’s impossible.

Comment: That is great, thanks again!

Comment: @M3xr: My pleasure.